# How can jQuery delete every element

Tags: jquery, html

How can jQuery delete every element separately by clicking the links blue, yellow, red ????

Unfortunately, find function does not manage to move throughout the tree dom.

project in: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VDh/

HTML markup:

```
<div class="view-products">
    <div class="view-header">
        <div class="reset_pol">
<a class="blue_" href="#">Blue</a><a class="yellow_" href="#">yellow</a><a class="red_" href="#">Red</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal jcarousel-navigation-after" style="position: relative; display: block;">
            <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal">
                <ul class="jcarousel jcarousel-view--listaoferowanychproduktow--block jcarousel-dom-1 jcarousel-processed jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; width: 3286px;">
                    <li class="odd jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" jcarouselindex="1" style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <div class="views-field views-field-field-kategoria">
                            <div class="field-content">
                                <div class="blue">
                                    content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="even jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal" jcarouselindex="2" style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <div class="views-field views-field-field-kategoria">
                            <div class="field-content">
                                <div class="yellow">
                                    content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="odd jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3" style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <div class="views-field views-field-field-kategoria">
                            <div class="field-content">
                                <div class="red">
                                    content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="even jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-4 jcarousel-item-4-horizontal" jcarouselindex="4" style="float: left; list-style: none;">
                        <div class="views-field views-field-field-kategoria">
                            <div class="field-content">
                                <div class="red">
                                content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I have created the following security code jQuery:

```
(function () {

            $('.blue_').click(function(event){
                   $(this).closest('.blue');
            })  
}());
```

Comment: Need clarification on what you're trying to do. What, specifically, are you trying to delete, and when?

Comment: I want it for every click of the link delete every class blue, yellow, red independently.

Comment: And after you click the class members are automatically added

Comment: So you want to remove the element from the carousel and after clicking again it has to be added again? And do you want to remove just the class, the div with the class or the whole li (carousel element) it sits in?

Comment: My mistake. Could I modify the code teeth removed the red and yellow-class after clicking the class blue

Comment: It's still not clear what you exactly try to achieve, but I've edited my answer to what I think is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's still not completely clear what you want, please see this code and tell me if that comes close to what you want (see also this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VDh/4/)):

```
$('.blue_').click(function(event){
   switchClass('blue');
});
$('.yellow_').click(function(event){
   switchClass('yellow');
});
$('.red_').click(function(event){
   switchClass('red');
});
function switchClass(selectedClass) {
    var classes = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
    for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (selectedClass == classes[i]) {
            $('.was_'+selectedClass).addClass(selectedClass).removeClass('was_'+selectedClass);
        } else {
            $('.'+classes[i]).addClass('was_'+classes[i]).removeClass(classes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanation:
I added a function to prevent some duplicate code. In the function the class that is clicked keeps (or gets) it's original class (e.g. .blue) while the others get "was_" appended to them (e.g. was_red).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(function () {
    $('.blue_, .yellow_, .red_').click(function (event) {
        var cls = $(this).attr('class'); // Get the class name
        cls = cls.substring(0, cls.length - 1); // Remove `_` from the class name
        $('.' + cls).remove(); // Remove the element with the class name of clicked anchor without _
    })
}());
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VDh/3/)**

Comment: Do you authorization can I modify the code teeth removed the red and yellow-class after clicking the class blue

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you rephrase?

Comment: My mistake. Could I modify the code teeth removed the red and yellow-class after clicking the class blue –

Comment: So you want to remove all classes red, yellow and blue when click `blue_` button?

Comment: remove red, yellow when clik blue

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.blue_').click(function(event){
   $('.blue').remove();
})
```

or this:

```
$('.blue_').click(function(event){
      $(this).closest('.view-products').find('.blue').remove();
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VDh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(event){
                   $(this).hide();
            })
```